# English to European-Portuguese translator

Tags: translation, google-translate

I am using Google Translator for multilingual support. As far as I googled, it provides only Brazilian Portuguese & not European Portuguese. Is there any other translator/API(Free or Licence) that could provide European Portuguese. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure google translate covers European as well as Brazilian Portuguese.

Just entered a bunch of words that are only used in Portugal such as

- Descapotável
- Fixe
- Aferrolhar
- Gajo

and they provided the correct translation into English. I did have to set the source language as Portuguese ( if left to autodetect in some cases it failed to detect the language )

The google api documentation shows both Portugal and Brazil as being covered ( see code 'pt')

Comment: the problem is not the portuguese > english translating. it's the other way around. "guy" becomes "cara", "cool" becomes "legal", "i'm eating" becomes "estou comendo", etc. all of which are very typical brazilian-portuguese words/expressions and not used in european-portuguese

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the most consistent translation matrix between American English (en_US) and European Portuguese (pt_PT) that's available online is the **[DeepL Translator](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator)**/[DeepL API](https://www.deepl.com/pro-api). Their paid offering, **[DeepL Pro](https://www.deepl.com/pro)**, takes it a step further to supplying formal and informal tones for both regions and represents the pinnacle of machine translation for European Portuguese that I've personally used.

**[Bing Translator](https://www.bing.com/translator)** also offers an explicit choice between European and Brazilian Portuguese translations and does a fair job at minding the differences, though it appears less nuanced about the vernacular usage than DeepL.

Both of these are far superior to Google's offerings when working with Portuguese. As a participant in their Crowdsource project and the support forums for it, according to the Google representatives there (as of Q4 2021), there remains no official plan to fork the Portuguese part of the database into Brazilian and European variants despite years of requests for it.